# Customize PointLabels in PrimeFaces chart

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, jqplot, managed-bean

Need some reference to customize the pointLabels in a PrimeFaces redered chart, I'm already using the property of *setShowPointLabels* as true in my Java Class, but it actually gives me no parameter to customize directly the point labels generated by jqPlot, just the property of *show* as true, but not the actual values displayed on the chart in the point labels.

To recover the point labels instance of the chart, I'm using:

```
var points = this.cfg.seriesDefaults.pointLabels;
```

Getting this value:

```
Object {
  hideZeros: true,
  show: true,
  __proto__: Object
}
```

There is some way that I can customize these point labels recovering the displayed values directly on jqPlot or setting it on the Managed Bean?

Comment: See the jqPlot docs: http://www.jqplot.com/examples/point-labels.php  You can use PF extender functionality to extend the JS before the chart is created. See this doc from PF: https://primefaces.github.io/primefaces/8_0/#/components/chart?id=extender

Comment: I didn't get any result, even using PrimeFaces chart extender and customizing it with with Vanilla in the jqPlot extender, I didn't get how the pointLabels arrays are rendered, specially with the series that have more than one value (stacked horizontal chart). Anyways, thanks for sharing jqPlot native documentation, helped a lot.